# My very first SSD - slow, resource hog?

Tags: windows, performance, hard-drive, ssd, file-transfer

I just bought my very first internal SSD and installed it into my desktop PC. I was running out of disk space and want to use it for data storage. The OS is installed on the first disk, which is a standard (spinning) HDD.

This is what Samsung Magician is showing me:

[Drive Details](https://i.ibb.co/vQpXW8r/Drive-Details.png)

[Performance Benchmark](https://i.ibb.co/n6RJV7D/Performance-Benchmark.png)

[Firmware](https://i.ibb.co/HnVyscF/Firmware.png)

So "on paper", everything seems to look great. However, when I'm trying to move files from my HDD to the SSD, I'm only getting about 50-70 MB/s. I assumed that the bottleneck here is the speed limit of the HDD read access...

What I don't understand is **why this bogs down my whole system**. I would expect Windows 7 to be smart enough not to allow itself freeze up during simple file transfer operations. Also, the PC has 32 GB RAM and a 3,4 GHz 12-core CPU, so it's not exactly slow.

What might be the problem here? The system gets so slow that I cannot even open Firefox while moving files. Shouldn't the system somehow manage the amount of resources processes can take and put a cap on it in order to ensure stability? Is there some setting that I could change to address the issue?

Unfortunately, I have little to no experience managing Windows systems. I know that in Linux one can impose custom limits on the resource usage of individual processes. However, file I/O seems something rather fundamental so I'd expect this to be efficiently managed by the OS.

Please help, the setup is not usable in this state...

PS.: I don't want to migrate the system to the SSD as I don't trust Windows with my data. The data should be stored on a separate drive, which is why I got the SSD in the first place. But this should not slow down my system on the HDD.

Comment: Your HDD would indeed seem to be the bottleneck, but without knowing the exact specs it's impossible to say if 50–70 MB/s is slow or not. That said, if the target disk is fast, I'd expect the source disk to try to provide data as fast as it can to keep up, leaving less room for other processes. The amount of RAM or CPU will have little or no impact on this.

Answer (score -3):

Problem 1: Windows and using explorer for file operations.

Problem 2 : possible unreadable sectors on HDD.

Problem 3: people generally overestimating the true performnace of SSDs.

What you can do:

- use a decent file manager for file copy-move operations
- check if the HDD has bad sectors or unreadble/reallocated ones; you can use HDTune for that
- check how fast you can copy a few GB of files from SSD to itself to have a general idea of the true performance of it

Other recommendations: get rid of the HDD and install the OS on SSD. Use 2 SSDs if you don't have a lot of data, OS on SSD and data on HDDs if you have large amounts of data.

A preferred method is to use the SSD with OS and a large HDD or array of HDDs for data storage. Since it's Windows 7 it will not be that drastic to use it on a HDD but if you switch to Windows 10 you're gonna be counting the days of your HDD's alive status.

Comment: -1 from me. 1) Using alternative copiers can sometimes improve performance, but Windows Explorer isn't so bad that it would bring the entire system down. It's good enough for 99% of users. 2) Bad sectors would be a plausible explanation, but they would give the same symptoms without the SSD. 3) OP says that copying files "bogs down the whole system". I'm reading this as the system becoming unresponsive. That's not just an unmet expectation.

Comment: Yes it is, because if it crashes your whole desktop may crash. Using a file manager prevents that and offers many performance and file management improvements.